# acceder a tablas de obdc con phyton

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, sqllite

Estoy intentando acceder a una base de datos de filemaker pro4, porque en el trabajo hay una base de datos con este formato y queremos actualizarlo porque se nos ha quedado corto tal y como está.

Pero al no tener el nombre de usuario ni contraseña con los privilegios adecuados (si tengo usuario y contraseña pero no de administrador), estoy pensando acceder mediante obdc, sqllite y programar en phyton

Pero mi problema es que no sé ni que tablas tiene por dentro ni la cantidad de las tablas para poder hacer las correspondientes consultas SQL o exportarlas a SQL.

Mi problema es que todos los códigos con obdc que veo para acceder me piden el nombre de las tablas..

¿alguien sabe como puedo realiazar un programa en phyton para poder acceder y que me devuelve el nombre de todas las tablas que contiene ese OBDC ?

Gracias..